# How to determine just by atomic spectra if the element has anomalous electron configuration?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, atomic-physics

Is it possible by using just atomic spectra energy levels data (e.g. from NIST Atomic Spectra Database) to determine if an element (e.g. Cr, Cu, Nb, Mo, Ru, Rh, Pd, Au etc.) has "anomalous electron configuration"?

(Or do we need additional data from chemical reactions e.g. valence electrons etc.?)

Comment: What do you mean with "anomalous electron configuration"?

Comment: Unusual order of filling of atomic orbitals. Sometimes it's called "violation of aufbau principle" - https://eic.rsc.org/feature/the-trouble-with-the-aufbau-principle/2000133.article

Comment: Some inconclusive discussion here http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/39970/how-it-was-observed-that-elements-in-columns-6-and-11-assume-abnormal-electron